# Why is $J(u) := \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2$ convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Define $J(u) := \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2$ over $\{ u \in H^1(\Omega) : tr(u) = g\}$.

Why is $J$ convex? I keep getting $J(tu + (1-t)v) \leq 2t^2J(u) + 2(1-t)^2J(v)$ by using the triangle inequality and $2ab \leq a^2 + b^2.$ What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square of a norm is always convex:
$$
\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\|^2 \le \big(\lambda\| x\| + (1-\lambda)\|y\|\big)^2\le \lambda \|x\|^2 + (1-\lambda) \|y|\|^2.
$$
The first inequality is convexity of the norm plus monotonocity of the square function, the second inequality uses convexity of the square function.

In a Hilbert space you can use the definition of the norm by the inner product and perform a brute-force computation:
$$\begin{split}
\frac12\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\|^2 -\frac\lambda2\|x\|^2 - \frac{1-\lambda}2\|y\|^2
&= -\frac{\lambda(1-\lambda)}2\left(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 + 2\langle x,y\rangle\right)\\
&= -\frac{\lambda(1-\lambda)}2\|x+y\|^2\\&
\le0
\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks.. The first inequality is just the triangle inequality.

Comment: Expanding the middle term, $(\lambda |x| + (1-\lambda)|y|)^2 = |\lambda|^2|x|^2 + (1-\lambda)^2|y|^2 + 2\lambda(1-\lambda)|x||y|$, should it not be easy to see the results by doing something to the last term here? I understand you used convexity of $x \to x^2$ but still..

Comment: See my edit. The trick is to start with the difference of all terms in the defining inequality for convexity. Took me a while to recall it :)